# Make a batch-file loop when there is internet or launch a program and exit when there is NO internet

Tags: batch-file

The idea is to have a batch file ping the internet every 5 minutes to see if there is a connection. If there is an internet connection the batch file will loop every 5 minutes to ping again. If there is NO internet connection then the batch file will launch a program and exit. I created a batch file that does everything but exit when the internet is not detected.

What I have so far loops just the way it should but I'm stuck at making the file exit if the internet connection is NOT connected and `notepad.exe` is launched. I don't know much about batch-files and am trying to piece things together from searches, I need help.

```
@echo off
setlocal

cls

:loop

@ping 209.222.18.218 -n 1 -w 1000> nul

if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 start C:\windows\notepad.exe

timeout /t 60 >null

goto loop
```

Expected result: the batch file pings the internet every 5 minutes to detected either there is or isn't an internet connection. If there is an internet connection the batch file will loop every 5 minutes. If there isn't an internet connection the batch file will launch `notepad.exe` and then exit itself.

Actual result, I get the batch file to loop when it detects internet but I can't get it to exit itself when there is NO internet.

Comment: Just place your two commands within parentheses, `(Start Notepad & Exit /B)`, and for `5` minutes, you want `Timeout 300 /NoBreak>Nul`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rearrange your lines a bit:

```
:loop
timeout 300 >nul
ping 209.222.18.218 -n 1 -w 1000 |find "TTL=" >nul
if %errorlevel%==0 goto :loop
REM if not errorlevel 1 goto :loop
start C:\windows\notepad.exe
```

Use *one* of the `if` lines - whichever you are more comfortable with.

Comment: Thanks, a new issue is happening and I'm not sure if it's related to the find TTL part. I put the find TTL in the script and it seems to now randomly set off notepad, even when the internet is still up. If there's internet the ping should work every time right? I'm using errorlevel 0 is this not the correct errorlevel? Should I even use errorlevel? The script should ping the internet reliably, if there's ANY response saying there is internet then the script can loop, if it pings and the result says no internet overall then the script will run notepad. Is there a way to ping reliably?

Comment: Even on a good connection, it's not guaranteed, that each `ping` pongs back. You can change `-w 1000` to `-w 5000` to extend the timeout. Or change `-n 1` to `-n 4`.`find`, so notepad starts only, when all four pings got no response. Or do both. // `ping ... |find "TTL="` is the most reliable way, as discussed several times here on SO. (ping's own errorlevel is not reliable; A response like "Reply from <localhost>: <destination> unreachable` **is** a reply, so ping will return an errorlevel of zero (at least with IPv4))

Comment: I tried all your suggestions in your last reply and they made no difference the script kept triggering even with internet every few minutes. What's crazy right now is when I take out |find "TTL=" the script becomes seemingly stable. I'm still testing where I have a .txt file being generated with the ping info once it's triggered. So far so good no trigger yet. I also read about TTL being a reliable ping method but for some reason in my case this is untrue, albeit I don't understand why.

Comment: That's very strange. Try `>ping.log 2>&1` instead of `>nul` (just the `ping`, without the `find`) to log the output and check for anomalies.

Comment: OK I removed the "find" bit of code and added your log suggestion. Over 8 hours and the script randomly tripped and started nodepad and to my surprise NOTHING was logged, NOTHING. I even placed the log code in other scripts to see if they were the culprit but again nothing logs when the script runs on its own. In testing everything works perfectly so I'm kind of stumped. For now I have stopped the script from looping and have replaced the loop with an exit and then run this script in the task scheduler and make task scheduler loop the script in hopes this stops the random start of notepad.

Comment: Well I'm at a lose. The script triggered again, this time about 16 hours in. Nothing tells my why, none of the >ping.log 2>&1 that I put in work when the script is automated through Task Scheduler. If I manually click on the script it works as expected and I see log files generated. No logs are specific in Event Viewer. I know the script is triggering but I don't understand why. I seem to have internet, no drops are happening because I have YouTube running during the times this is supposed to be  happening. No other apps programs tell me that the internet has been lose not even for a blip.....

Comment: The only thing I can thing of is is that the script at some point in its cycle cant ping the internet or ping at all once it's ran coincidentally perhaps in it's timing with whatever possibly cant ping at that moment (hardware or software) hence triggering and starting notepad. The trigger timing pattern is different every time so to me it looks like it could be something to do with what actually pings when command prompt asks to ping if that makes scenes. For example the command to ping is sent but for some reason the computer at that time cant ping even though there is actually internet. IDK

Comment: Alright, well this is now off the main subject of how to loop which you answered for me so, thank you Stephan. If I ever find out what is causing this i'll post back. Thanks again!

Comment: Update: Turns out pinging 209.222.18.218 is unreliable, trace route shows time outs consistently. This was the root of the problem. Now I'm pinging 1.1.1.1 and feel confident pinging this IP will work for my purposes.

Comment: @RickKnox Thank you for the feedback. That's exactly, what I suspected (that's why I suggested `-n 4` and/or `-w 5000` to compensate short "outages").